# I try to integrate a carousel bootstrap. The images do not resize in height

Tags: html, css, carousel

You can see my many problems on this page of my website.
Problems with the height of my images, with left and right contols and with indicators.

http://www.jeanlerin.com/peintures/peintures.html

I can not put the html and css code because I can not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `max-height` with CSS on your images, or use images with the same height ?

Comment: Thank you very much Damien, i can not use images with the same height, put i have set a "max-height" on my class : carousel.inner and it work fine